# Can I use both Radeon HD 4xxx and HD 6xxx?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, amd-radeon

Recently AMD pushed HD 4xxx drivers to "Legacy" version of their Catalyst driver package. New version of Catalyst that is required for HD 6xxx no longer has those drivers.

Now I can install legacy version and have HD 4xxx working or install normal version and have HD 6xxx working.

They both worked happily with older version of normal driver package.

Am I supposed to use outdated driver for HD 6xxx just to have HD 4xxx working as well?

Comment: Just keep the old version of the drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound That's what AMD advised when HD 4xxx was new and hot and people were using it together with cards that were considered legacy back then.

Btw. Last version of the drivers that supports both HD 4xxx and HD 6xxx is Catalyst 12.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've chosen so far to stick with the last version of the driver (12.4) that supported both HD 4xxx and HD 6xxx.

But I'm still open for better ideas.

**UPDATE:**

I managed to use both cards with latest drivers.

1. I installed Legacy driver for HD4xxx
2. I exported the driver for my HD4290 with the http://www.grandutils.com/DriverExtractor/
3. I installed driver for HD6xxx (HD4290 stopped working)
4. I installed driver exported in step 2 through "Update driver" option of the HD4290 devide in Device Manger)

Both cards are working now.

Unfortunately on 64bit Win7 this solution causes some problems. Because the both drivers use same file names and files are to some degree incompatible it causes MMLoadDrv.exe to crash on windows startup and AMD Catalyst Control Center doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think your only options are to either keep using the old driver or upgrade the HD4xxx card to something that's still supported.

Comment: HD 4xxx is built into the motherboard. It's strange that you can't have legacy and new drivers at the same time.